# How to convert Odata v2 metadata xml file to swagger specification code?

Tags: xml, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have odata v2 metadata XML file , I need to convert the xml code into swagger 2.0 specification. What was the tool required? And If there is any tool how to install all those

Comment: What do you mean by "XML code"? A WSDL that describes a SOAP service? Or something else?

Comment: Can you attach an example of "XML code" and the expected result? Xml is a text file contain data; swagger is a specification for api. What do you need?

Comment: yeah i have odata v2 metadata xml file , i should convert that into swagger 2.0